# C# My main thread stops working when other threads stop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have problem. I have program in C#, which in main thread starts a few threads that should do some work simultaneously and waits for them to stop, just like this:

```
    public void start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.NrOfThreads; i++)
        {
            Threads[i].Start(imWithIndices[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.NrOfThreads; i++)
        {
            Threads[i].Join();
        }
    }
```

All threads are running the same function, but with different parameters. This is this function:

```
public void performOperation(Object image)
{
    try
    {
        ImageWithIndex im = (ImageWithIndex) image;
        IntPtr tranformedImage = dilatation(im.image, im.width, parameters.ImageHeight,
            parameters.ElemWidth, parameters.ElemHeight, parameters.CentrPntX, parameters.CentrPntY);
        this.transformedImages[im.index] = tranformedImage;
    }
    catch (Exception XD)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wątek nr " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ": " + XD.Message, XD.GetType().ToString());
    }
}
```

So the problem is that when all threads stop, my main thread does not continue working, but it also stops and I have no idea why. Even more stranger is fact that if `i` in `start()` function is equal to 1, so that I'm starting only one thread; everything works perfectly.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, there is nothing wrong with your code. because this is like the following could that I run without any problem

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        // Create an array of Thread references.
        Thread[] array = new Thread[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            // Start the thread with a ThreadStart.
            array[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Start));
            array[i].Start();
        }
        // Join all the threads.
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i].Join();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("DONE: {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    static void Start()
    {
        // This method takes ten seconds to terminate.
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

May be using MessageBox.Show method in your exception handling catch statement is wrong. Could you remove or comment that and test your code again?

or move your code to a console project and change the for loop that use Join like this and check the Output.

```
for (int i = 0; i < parameters.NrOfThreads; i++)
        {
            Threads[i].Join();
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} is Completed",i);
        }
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment instead of answer.